# getting a error called :: too many indices for array

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Im getting a error "IndexError: too many indices for array" im new to phyton, i only know this has something to do with the dimension of the array, but dont know how to fix, Please help

The Y variable im using in this is taken from this

```
X = df.iloc[:, 3].values.reshape(-1, 1) #Life expectanacy
Y = df.iloc[:, 6].values.reshape(-1, 1) #Alcohol
```

```
    def compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y):
        abs_difference_matrix = np.array([[0,1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
        n_samples = Y.shape[0]
        # compute the absolute difference matrix
        # and remember to return the matrix
        # INSERT YOUR CODE HERE

        for i in range(n_samples):
            for j in range(n_samples):
                abs_difference_matrix[i, j] = abs(Y[i] - Y[j])

        return abs_difference_matrix
```

```
   # compute the absolute difference matrix
   abs_difference_matrix = compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y_pred)

   # visualise the matrix
   # INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
   ax.set_title("Absolute difference matrix for Y_pred")
   cax = ax.imshow(abs_difference_matrix)
   cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-d9df7ea6b677> in <module>
      6 
      7 # compute the absolute difference matrix
----> 8 abs_difference_matrix = compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y_pred)
      9 
     10 # visualise the matrix

<ipython-input-77-0adc297bd3d4> in compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y)
     15     for i in range(n_samples):
     16         for j in range(n_samples):
---> 17             abs_difference_matrix[i, j] = abs(Y[i] - Y[j])
     18 
     19     return abs_difference_matrix

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Try `abs_difference_matrix[i][j]`.

Comment: i got a new error called "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" when i replaced, abs_difference_matrix[i, j] = abs(Y[i] - Y[j])  To  abs_difference_matrix[i][j] = abs(Y[i] - Y[j])

Comment: Check the length of `Y`. Maybe it has a different shape than you expect.

Comment: You should check the shape of `abs_difference_matrix`. It's shape is quite... unique. The `IndexError` may be because of this.

Comment: when i do "Y.shape" i get "(2938,)"  its one dimensional

Comment: lahsuk, i changed this part to "abs_difference_matrix = np.array()" and got this error instead "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
X = df.iloc[:, 3].values.reshape(-1, 1) #Life expectanacy
Y = df.iloc[:, 6].values.reshape(-1, 1) #Alcohol

def compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y):
    n_samples = Y.shape[0]
    abs_difference_matrix = np.empty([n_samples,n_samples])
    # compute the absolute difference matrix
    # and remember to return the matrix
    # INSERT YOUR CODE HERE

    for i in range(n_samples):
        for j in range(n_samples):
            abs_difference_matrix[i][j] = abs(Y[i] - Y[j])

    return abs_difference_matrix

# compute the absolute difference matrix
abs_difference_matrix = compute_abs_difference_matrix(Y_pred)

# visualise the matrix
# INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_title("Absolute difference matrix for Y_pred")
cax = ax.imshow(abs_difference_matrix)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
```

Comment: George, ive got another problem i asked a question, could you please help me out in that as well